# Lose weight at home?

Tags: cardio, bodyweight-exercises

I have a question that's been runnin round my mind for a while now..... I don't have access to a gym, so I decided about doing body weight exercise but I don't know which ones to do!?! I'm not fat but I'm no skinny either, I have a little bit of lower belly fat and I can see a little bit of my lower ab, should I do cardio before body weights? Or should I not do cardio at all?

Answer (score 1):

There is no definitive answer to the question of which order you should do these things in.

As for whether or not you should do cardio; yes, you should.

But keep in mind, if you want to lose weight, you're better of adjusting your diet first, and exercise second. Exercising does NOT compensate for an untidy and lazy diet.